# Weather App Hourly Scroll Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I see in a few places that people are looking for the weather app effect. A lot of those questions are for android apps or JAVA, but I'm looking for the use on an HTML/CSS/Javascript site. Is this even possible?

**I'm specifically looking for the finger/cursor scroll effect when you look at the hourly forecast.**

Pointing me in ay direction would really help.
Even if I have to dig into another language like Ruby on Rails, that would be helpful to know.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by weather app effect, like a rain or snow overlay on top of content? Try to supply some additional information.

Comment: No, just the scrolling effect so you can see the forecast in the next few hours. So a line of either images, or icons where you can swipe to see more info. I was thinking there would be an overflow: hidden element in there somewhere and maybe some of the newer CSS animations.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, if you wish to implement a feature where the user can swipe left or right between images or areas then you should consider looking at a framework like Hammer.js http://hammerjs.github.io/ or Zingchart https://zingchart.github.io/zingtouch/.

These are Javascript library's that allow you to implement gesture functionality to a website.